# How to replace outer query value if subquery returns null

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM main_menu AS m WHERE EXISTS(select * from menu where menu.main_menu_id = m.main_menu_id AND menu.menu IS NOT NULL)
```

Above query shows rows from main_menu table only if their respective rows in menu table is not NULL, which is correct.

But I would like to do something more. If the value for menu table(subquery) found NULL , the main_menu value(outer query) should be altered,something like using `IFNULL` but for the outer query. How do I do that, please?

Comment: you can use left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should use a `LEFT JOIN` and not `EXISTS()` statement :

```
SELECT m.*,COALESCE(m2.<Column>,OtherValue),....
FROM main_menu m
LEFT JOIN menu m2
 ON(m2.main_menu_id = m.maid_menu_id AND m2.menu is not null)
```

This will join both tables even when there is no such record, and will have `NULL` values for all menu columns.

You didn't define 'should be altered' , so that's the best I can come up with.

Comment: does the COALESCE change main_menu with other string if its' subquery returned null?

Comment: @Keren yes, that's the same as `IFNULL` , first input is the column, second one is the value to replace when null.